# Why is this arm bone bending the other way after exiting edit mode?

Tags: bones

I have a bone and I'm giving it a slight bend for a pole target, and on the right side of this image

[image]

the arm is bent the other way. Its also bending the other way when I move the ik. Help please.

Comment: it's changing right when I exit edit mode

Comment: there is no reason to pre-bend the IK chain for the pole bone. That is a nonsense and I don't know where this misconception comes from. Your X axis are probably flipped on the other half of your character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its standard practice to add a slight bend in the arms when in Edit Mode, which is what Faceb is eluding to.

That said, you can quickly fix your problem by changing your Pole Angle to 180.[image]

Comment: I found out its because I flipped the armature to the other side to make it symmetrical, but didn't change the pole angle. Thanks though I'll accept the answer!

Comment: Woa ok you should generally start rigging after you've done *all* your bone-making (for a lack of a better term).  Copying bones with constraints may seem like a time-saver, but it can lead to unforeseen issues when you start getting into more complex rig setups.

Comment: I know now, silly mistake from the past :)

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode you can add, scale, move, rotate the bones to make it your 'reference' pose armature. In Pose Mode you can rotate, move and scale (but not add) bones, since here you can only change the pose of the armature. So if you switch between Edit Mode and Pose Mode you see different poses, unless you reset the armature:

In Pose Mode, if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> with a bone selected, that bone will be reset (when you select every bone, the complete armature will be reset), according to how the bones are set up in Edit Mode. But I'm not sure if this is what you mean :)

Comment: I think the bone constraint is causing it to act up,  but its just an ik/pole target. heres the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZiQtohl3tmeDctbXIxV0RlTHc/view?usp=sharing